# Xamarin rejects EasyModbus .NET library with TypeLoadException on EasyModbus.ModbusClient field

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, modbus

Is there a way to make Xamarin accept the EasyModbus .NET library? Or is there an accepted Modbus library for Xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding the EasyModbus dll in reference and adding a ModbusClient.cs file with the same classes and function definitions. Solved the dependencies and it worked just fine.